# How to assign attributes or functions to objects added after DOm ready with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, underscore.js

I am working in some personal project it is like the front-end of a chat. So i have my users and i have  a JSON with the list of online and offline users. When the website firs load I also load plugins for custom scroll and  make elements draggable with jquery ui. what i would like to know is if there is a way to make the new elements added to the body (chat windows) automatically be scrollable and have this custom scroll bar every time  I add them. So far what I do es something like :

```
$(document).on("ready", functions);
function functions() {
    $("#contacts-container").slimScroll({
    height: '220',
    size: '10px',
    position: 'right',
    color: '#535a61',
    alwaysVisible: false,
    distance: '0',
    railVisible: true,
    railColor: '#222',
    railOpacity: 0.3,
    wheelStep: 10,
    disableFadeOut: false
});

$(".messages-container").slimScroll({
    height: '200',
    size: '10px',
    position: 'right',
    color: '#535a61',
    alwaysVisible: false,
    distance: '0',
    railVisible: true,
    railColor: '#222',
    railOpacity: 0.3,
    wheelStep: 10,
    disableFadeOut: false,
    start: "bottom"     
});
$("#online .user-name").on("click", checkUser);

};

function checkUser(){
console.log("clicked");
var user = $(this).html();
$.getJSON("js/options.json", function(json){
    var itemsLength = json.chat.OnlineContacts.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
        var jsonUserName = json.chat.OnlineContacts[i].name;
        var jsonUserStatus = json.chat.OnlineContacts[i].status;
        var jsonUserAvatar = json.chat.OnlineContacts[i].picture;
        if(user == jsonUserName){
            displayChatWindow(jsonUserName, jsonUserStatus, jsonUserAvatar);
        }
    };
});
}

function displayChatWindow(user, status, avatar){
console.log(avatar);
var template = _.template($("#windowTemplate").html(), {userName: user, userStatus: status, userAvatar: avatar});
$("body").prepend(template);
$(".messages-container").slimScroll({
    height: '200',
    size: '10px',
    position: 'right',
    color: '#535a61',
    alwaysVisible: false,
    distance: '0',
    railVisible: true,
    railColor: '#222',
    railOpacity: 0.3,
    wheelStep: 10,
    disableFadeOut: false,
    start: "bottom"     
});
$(".friend-window").draggable({handler: ".header"});
}
```

On the DisplayChatWindow I append the template wich is s div representing the chat window, but i also have to re add the slimScroll function and the draggabla function, but i would like them to automatically have it once i append it, I am learning Java Script so I don't know if using an object i can achieve this or if there is another way, basically what i have done here it the most i know how to do so far, i will appreciate if you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work I believe.

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    functions();
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
        $(".messages-container").slimScroll({
            height: '200',
            size: '10px',
            position: 'right',
            color: '#535a61',
            alwaysVisible: false,
            distance: '0',
            railVisible: true,
            railColor: '#222',
            railOpacity: 0.3,
            wheelStep: 10,
            disableFadeOut: false,
            start: "bottom"     
        });
   }); 
});
```